# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I  Need

- i  Need To append  Array data in div dynamically .

Output Array Response

```
 Array
           (
               [data] => Array
                   (
                       [0] => Array
                           (
                               [metadata] => Array
                                   (
                                       [summary] => Raj is the founder of  Accelerator, In first multi-city Tech Accelerator, backed by 20 iconic Digital founders and 5 leading venture funds from across the world. Rah is also the founder of Superangels network and curator of the Global Superangels Forum. He is the co-host and curator of Founders Forum India. Rahas made over 15 investments as an active and engaged angel investor.His journey has been a continuum of re-invention waves. In the first wave, he brought private radio (Times FM) to India in early nineties, and redefined Indian youth culture. In his second wave, he was at the cusp of early Internet culture in India and built Indim, the most valuable Internet business in India in 2005 (funded by Sequoia). In the third wave, Rah was at the centre of a massive transformation of the Indian film industry, where he oversaw (as President, Reliance Entertainment) the corporatization of mom and pop Bollywood businesses into multi-billion dollar enterprise. At Reliance, Rajesh found himself at the centre of cross-border investment and alignment between Hollywood and Indian Film Industry and one of the biggest investment deals (DreamWorks) in Hollywood. Currently in his fourth wave, Rajesh is building the vital building blocks of a nascent early stage startup ecosystem in India, and sees this as the biggest and most exciting challenge that he has faced in his life.Rajesh is an alumnus of Harvard Business School (AMP), and has a fellowship from London School of Economics.  Twitter URL: http://twitter.com/rajese: www.ga.com
                                   )

                           )
```

jquery code

```
       var id=$('#eventID').attr('value');
        alert(id);
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://local.domain.com/app.php/ajax?for=speakers&id="+id,
            success: function(html)
            {
                console.log(html);
                $.each(html, function(key, value){
                console.log(key + ":" + value)
                })

            }
        });
```

i have tried to debug

output after console.log(html) is :-

```
XHR finished loading: GET "http://local.10times.com/app.php/ajax?for=speakers&id=25162".
```

- output comes with no error.
- but i  when used foreach loop error comes.
- $(".speakers").append(html); ok no error .

Output i need

```
 <div class="speaker">summary data</div>
 <div class="speaker">summary data </div>
<div class="speaker">summary data </div>
<div class="speaker">summary data </div>
```

error

```
   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '19240' in Array.
```

Comment: Where exactly does the error occur? The console error should tell you which line of which file

Comment: problem is when i used foreach loop to store array data in div

Comment: is the response JSON ..?

Comment: no response is in array

Comment: $(".speakers").append(html) works fine but my req is us loop and store data in class dynimically

Comment: what data the `html` variable is having?